# Problems with related_name with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have problems with relate_name on my model. On the class 'Pildora' there is a ForeignKey on the field: bloque. I have indicated the relate_name, but it doesn't work.

I have these models:

```
class Bloque(models.Model):
    titulo          = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    letra           = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    descripcion     = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tema            = models.ForeignKey(Tema, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=1)
    updated_at      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Pildora(models.Model):
    titulo              = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    descripcion         = RichTextField(max_length=2000, config_name='default')
    slug                = models.SlugField(max_length=20)
    url                 = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    tipo                = models.ForeignKey(TipoPildora, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    identificador       = models.IntegerField()
    pildora_anterior    = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    bloque              = models.ForeignKey(Bloque, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related')
    activo              = models.BooleanField()
    created_at          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

But when i use:

```
bloque = Bloque.objects.filter(tema__asignatura__slug=kwargs["asignatura"], tema__slug=kwargs["tema"], slug=kwargs["bloque"])
print(bloque.formacion_pildora_related)
```

Django says:

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'formacion_pildora_related'
```

I read the django doc, but I can't find why is this happening :S
What could i do?

PS: In the case in question %(app_label)s_%(class)s_related refers to 'formacion_pildora_bloque'. I have put fixed names like 'pildoras' or even left it unreported, so that by default it is used as 'set_pillora', but none of this works.

Thank you so much all, really. I'm stuck and a little frustrated.

Comment: What output do you expect here? The related attribute is on individual model instances, not on the queryset. Try  `print(bloque[0].formacion_pildora_related)`

Comment: As I read in the documentation, by using relate_name you can bring back information from the foreignkey related model. Isn't that right?

Comment: Oh, it works!!! I didn't expect that. Thank you so much, Haken Lid. You helped me a lot!!